# Anchor Tag with onclick/JavaScript attribute. Stop refreshing page in I.E

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a HTML/JavaScript project that holds a few dozen anchor tags; each of the anchor tags calls the same JavaScript function, but with a different parameter.

Everything looks good in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer (IE) the page seems to reload (flicker) every time I click an anchor tag (like the one shown below). How can I make IE stop reloading/flickering? I would prefer not to rewrite the whole script. I have tried onclcick='javascript... and href='javascript...,but both have the same problem (although onclick seems a little better).

```
<a onclick='javascript:foo(22)'></a>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `<a onclick='foo(22); return false;'></a>`

Also, `javascript:` is pointless in event attributes as it just defines a label.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to use jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="action" rel="22"></a>
<script>
    $('.action').click(function(){
        yourfunction($(this).attr('rel');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How is this simpler than the accepted answer? It looks less readable to begin with.

Comment: This is a 4 year old answer and highly irrelevant by now. Two things though, the answers are from roughly the same time, I wouldn't have added it if I saw the answer above. The other thing, inline JS is not great, in general. Some separation is nice to have. The choice of jQuery is questionable though.